# How to get proxy server's IP and my port number

Tags: proxy, tar, tor

I am using my college WI-FI while installing TOR browser it requires my proxy servers' IP and Port Number. How can I get this?

I used `traceroute` but I don't know how to find above with help of this. Especially, port number.

Comment: There might not be one.  Are you sure there's a proxy in the system that you are on?

Comment: yes, port number should be my system, I guess.